# Express-brute failing to send error message to page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

To combat brute force prevention in my NodeJS/Express application, I decided to use the [express-brute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-brute) package in my routing file. I use the package to prevent users from guessing a certain code randomly instead of inputting the unique code they are given.

I set up the rate-limiter object using the `express-brute-mongo` store (with MongoDB), as follows:

```
// setup the brute force prevention system
var expressBrute = require('express-brute');
var mongoStore = require('express-brute-mongo');
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var store = new mongoStore(function(ready) {
    mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/app", function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            ready(db.collection('bruteforce-store'));
        }
    });
});
var bruteforce = new expressBrute(store, {
    freeRetries: 2,            // only allow 2 incorrect requests
    minWait: 5 * 1000,         // min wait time of 5 seconds
    maxWait: 5 * 60 * 1000,    // max wait time of 5 minutes

    // use default callback function if all retries are used
    failCallback: expressBrute.FailTooManyRequests
});
```

The `failCallback` property is meant to be called when too many requests are made, and I set this to one of `express-brute`'s default callbacks, which is *supposed* to send a JSON error message in response. However, while the  prevention system does work (I can't attempt any more retries), this error message is never sent.

What's very odd is that the callback *is* run, as when I replace the callback with something like

```
failCallback: function(req,resp,next,nextdate) {
    console.log("too many requests");
    resp.json({ message: 'too many requests' });
}
```

I do get the message "too many requests" in my console, while the JSON command seems to be ignored. I've even tried making a GET request in the callback and redirecting to another page if too many requests are made, but still nothing happens except for output to the console. This leaves me unable to provide any sort of message to the user about their being locked out from the website. I'm confused as to why I'm unable to change the webpage at all when using `express-brute`. Is there any way I can change the webpage from the callback?

Comment: show me your whole code ??